# How do you fill mongoose entities with values based on an interface?

Tags: typescript, mongoose, nestjs, typescript-typings

I'm working on a NestJS API and I'm trying to create some documents with mongoose, but i'm running into some problems. I was following the [NestJS Mongo Docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/mongodb) and an [Auth0 API Guide](https://auth0.com/blog/modern-full-stack-development-with-nestjs-react-typescript-and-mongodb-part-1/) to get a good grip of what you are supposed to do.

> [NOTE] I removed all obvious and out-of-scope imports on the code blocks. I also registered the models als they should be, so that's nothing to question either. It is also **necessary** that I can fill the values in myself, since in the real world product I have to do calculations to fill in the values. That's why I decided to fill in the values first, instead of just passing the DTO to the mongoose entity.

This is my mongoose document entity:

```js
// src/user/interfaces/user.interface.ts
import { Document } from 'mongoose';

export interface User extends Document {
   readonly string firstName;
   readonly string lastName;
   readonly string fullName;
}
```

But.. when I try to fill the values in the service like this:

```js
// src/user/user.service.ts
import { User } from './interfaces/user.interface';

@Injectable();
export class UserService {
  constructor(
    @InjectModel("User")
    private readonly userModel: Model<User>,
  ) {}

  async createUser(dto: CreateUserDTO): Promise<User> {
    const user: User = {
       firstName: dto.firstName,
       lastName: dto.lastName,
       fullName: `${dto.firstName} ${dto.lastName}`,
    }
    return await this.userModel.create(user);
  }
}
```

It results in the following error and won't compile:

```
Type '{ firstName: string; lastName: string; fullName: string; }'
  is missing the following properties from type 'User': increment, model, $isDeleted, remove, and 52 more.ts(2740)
```

These, of course are errors since it extends the Mongoose Document and those values aren't filled.

---

I have tried the following already but I wasn't pleased with the "solutions"

### **Attempt 1**

*Pass it directly as an argument, unfortunately this does not give me the autocomplete and validation*

```js
async createUser(dto: CreateUserDTO): Promise<User> {
  const newUser = new this.userModel({
    firstName: dto.firstName,
    lastName: dto.lastName,
    fullName: `${dto.firstName} ${dto.lastName}`,
  });
  return await newUser.save();
}
```

---

### **Attempt 2**

*Make second interface and use interface A in the filling, and interface B in the returning and calling*

```js
// src/user/interfaces/user.interface.ts
import { Document } from 'mongoose';

export interface User {
   readonly string firstName;
   readonly string lastName;
   readonly string fullName;
}

export interface UserDoc extends User, Document {}
```

and then use it in the service like:

```js
// src/user/user.service.ts
import { User, UserDoc } from './interfaces/user.interface';

@Injectable();
export class UserService {
  constructor(
    @InjectModel("User")
    private readonly userModel: Model<UserDoc>,
  ) {}

  async createUser(dto: CreateUserDTO): Promise<UserDoc> {
    const user: User = {
       firstName: dto.firstName,
       lastName: dto.lastName,
       fullName: `${dto.firstName} ${dto.lastName}`,
    }
    return await this.userModel.create(user);
  }
}
```

Now, this works, but it's really ugly and you also have to make sure you are using the right interface at the right time, so quite inconvenient.

---

**TL;DR; Is there a way to have a strongly-typed mongoose entities, in which you can put the values which will get autocompleted like in `Attempt B` but better and cleaner?**